# Remote Connection to MariaDB not working when in different Network

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have MariaDB Version 10.5.12-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 Raspbian 11 installed on my Raspberry Pi.

I have setup my firewall to allow access to port 3306 from everywhere: `sudo ufw status`

| To | Action | From |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 3306 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 22 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 3306 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |

My sql users are as follows: `SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;`

| Host | User |
| --- | --- |
| % | Marvin34565 |
| % | root |
| localhost | mariadb.sys |
| localhost | mdbbackup |
| localhost | mysql |
| localhost | root |

I also commented out the `bind-address = <ip-address>` part in my */etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf* file.

Other config lines are not present in any config file in my */etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/* or */etc/mysql/conf.d/* directories.

When connection from my devices in the same network, everything works like a charm. Both for the root and Marvin34565 user. But as soon as I switch out of my network (the hotspot of my phone) I can't connect to the DB anymore.

I have tried everything I could find on various sites but couldn't make it work. So, any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect to anything between the two networks? For example http? ssh? ping? This might be a routing or firewall configuration issue, nothing to do with mariadb configuration.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I can't ping my network from the other one. Do you have a hint on how to fix this as I am not very familiar with networking stuff yet..

Comment: I'm not a networking expert, but I know enough to know there are many possible causes. As I mentioned above, routing and firewalls are likely candidates. I don't know anything about your network. This question is probably better to be asked on a sister site like serverfault.com, because Stack Overflow is for questions about code problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Bills suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785802/remote-connection-to-mariadb-not-working-when-in-different-network#comment126859760_71785802) I noticed that - indeed - I couldn't ping between my networks.
After setting up a port forward from my router to my Pi everything works as it should!